Manipulate iframe content
I want to be able to change the contents of an html iframe tag, how do I do that?
Like something like this:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="a.html" id="if">
    </body>
</html>
<script>
const iframe = document.getElementById("if");
iframe.document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "text";
<script>

a.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="text">.</p>
    </body>
</html>


You'll want to use contentWindow. By the way, it's getElementById(...), not getElementByID(...) (notice the difference in case).

Note that you can only do this if the iframe is in the same domain as the main page.

put that as an answer
